# markup in custom error messages using ParsleyJS

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I'm using ParsleyJS to validate a form.
I'm using custom error messages too using this syntax:

```
<input type="text" id="qd-amount" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required">
```

That works just fine but I'd like to add some markup in the message, like a link for sending the user to an help section. I've tried something like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="qd-amount" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="<a href=\"someurl\">Click here for help</a>">
```

But that seems to break the markup of the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would  `<input type="text" id="qd-amount" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="<a href=&quot;someurl&quot;>Click here for help</a>">` work?

Answer (score 3):

<s>You should probably use `'` instead of `"` inside your `<a>` element.</s> You should always escape HTML characters. If you're using PHP use `htmlentities()` or find a similar method in the server side language you're using or use a javascript method.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").parsley();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.1.2/parsley.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="qd-amount" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="<a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;>Click here for help</a>" />
    <input type="submit" />    
</form>
```

---

**Edit**: following Alex's comment, Parsley allows you to customize messages by data attributes. Other than that you can create a custom validator via javascript for this purpose, but since OP only wanted a custom message for a required field I'm not sure this is worth the trouble.

The custom message in the data attribute will always need to be escaped, either manually or via a function that escapes HTML characters (either in a server side language or javascript).

For purposes of completeness, here are two examples, one with the quotes escaped and the other with a custom validator. Beware this code is using the latest Parsley version - 2.8.1

```js
window.Parsley.addValidator('custom', {
    requirementType: 'string',
    validateString: function(value) {
        return value.length !== 0;
    },
    messages: {
        en: '<a href="http://google.com">so called "noobs" -  Click here for help for other field</a>'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.1/parsley.min.js"></script>

<form data-parsley-validate="">
    <input type="text" id="qd-amount" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="<a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;>so called &quot;noobs&quot; -  Click here for help</a>" />
    <input type="text" id="other-qd-amount" data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-custom=""/>
    <input type="submit" />    
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like a hack to me :-) I mean, it's fine, that is why I up-vote - but what if we have double quotes in the text, like `so called "noobs" - click here for help`

Comment: @Alex I understand it feels like a hack, but it is what the plugin supports and is specified on the documentation. I've expanded my answer to make sure whoever needs this remembers to escape HTML characters. Thanks.